# IWriterConfiguration.ReferenceHeaderPrefix equivalent in newer versions of CsvHelper

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, csvhelper

What is the equivalent of csvWriter.Configuration.ReferenceHeaderPrefix in the newer version of CsvHelper? Trying this

`csvWriter.Configuration.ReferenceHeaderPrefix = (memberType, memberName) => $"{memberName}_";`

but its not let me because ReferenceHeaderPrefix has only get method after version 20.0.0

Comment: The usual workflow is to construct an instance of the [`CsvConfiguration`](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/blob/master/src/CsvHelper/Configuration/CsvConfiguration.cs) class and pass that into the constructor for the reader or writer.  And [`CsvConfiguration.ReferenceHeaderPrefix`](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/blob/f3d8038950ee9d58c2f5e4cb31a69a4cb62528bd/src/CsvHelper/Configuration/CsvConfiguration.cs#L138) does have a `set` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual workflow is to construct an instance of the [`CsvConfiguration`](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/blob/master/src/CsvHelper/Configuration/CsvConfiguration.cs) class and pass that into the constructor for the reader or writer.  And [`CsvConfiguration.ReferenceHeaderPrefix`](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/blob/f3d8038950ee9d58c2f5e4cb31a69a4cb62528bd/src/CsvHelper/Configuration/CsvConfiguration.cs#L138) does have a `set` method.

```
var config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
{
    ReferenceHeaderPrefix = (args) => $"{args.MemberName}_",
};
using (var writer = new StreamWriter("path\\to\\file.csv"))
using (var csv = new CsvWriter(writer, config))
{
    // Write your CSV records here.
    csv.WriteRecords(records);
}
```

Note also that, in the current version (27.2.0), the [`ReferenceHeaderPrefix`](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/blob/9b5af7c61fd34ba7a508adf4417260db308def2b/src/CsvHelper/Delegates/ReferenceHeaderPrefix.cs) takes a single [`ReferenceHeaderPrefixArgs`](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/blob/9b5af7c61fd34ba7a508adf4417260db308def2b/src/CsvHelper/Delegates/ReferenceHeaderPrefix.cs#L21) argument, which contains `MemberType` and `MemberName` fields:

> ```
> public readonly struct ReferenceHeaderPrefixArgs
> {
>   public readonly Type MemberType;
>
>   public readonly string MemberName;
>
>   public ReferenceHeaderPrefixArgs(Type memberType, string memberName)
>   {
>       MemberType = memberType;
>       MemberName = memberName;
>   }
> }
> ```